# Word that describe the feeling when you are too excited about a thing to happen in the way you think it should but it doesn't

Tags: single-word-requests

My question is about a word.
I know it's kind of weird but I saw the definition of this word in dictionary once (maybe Oxford or Cambridge, I'm not sure..). But now I cannot remember the definition of the word and also what the word is. Kind of bothering me these days.
That's why I came here and ask you guy this. Have any one seen or known it?

> I couldn't remember this word, and I thought it was this really special word. But, it felt ________ when I figured out what the word was, because it wasn't that special after all.

Comment: Anxious? Disappointed?

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the text in your question at the time I am answering...

> Word that describe the feeling when you are too excited about a thing to happen in the way you think it should but it doesn't

You seem to be expressing that there is excitement from anticipation of an outcome, but the outcome is different from what was expected. You don't express that there is a let down because of that, but assuming there is, I believe the word your are wanting is ***anticlimactic***:

> causing unhappiness by being less exciting than expected or not as interesting as something that happened earlier:
>   *The announcement of his resignation was **anticlimactic**, as we all knew he could no longer stay in the job.*
>   <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/anticlimactic)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> [***crestfallen***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crestfallen) - disappointed and sad because of having failed unexpectedly

This word cojurs up the expectation of something, only to have hopes quashed.

Comment: This is not the word I'm looking for (fyi it's anticlimax) but I have learned a new word from you. Thank you so much for your help :D